# NSAutoreleasePool and class variables

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory, memory-management

I'm getting what looks like a crash due to overreleasing but as far as I can tell I'm not doing anything wrong, however I may have the wrong idea about AutoreleasePools and class variables.

If I have a class variable:

```
UIImageView *imageView;
```

and I allocate it in a thread like so:

```
 - (void)setupThreaded {
     NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"];
     imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

     [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addViewOnMainThread) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

     [pool release];
}

- (void)addViewOnMainThread {
    [self.view addSubView:imageView];
}
```

I'm currently occasionally getting an error suggesting that either imageView was prematurely released OR that imageView's image is getting prematurely released.

What could be causing that?

Comment: Note that you should not do `[pool release];`, but should do `[pool drain];`.  You're never supposed to release an NSAutoreleasePool.

Comment: @Daniel: In a non-GC environment (iOS), -drain and -release are equivalent, and you are allowed to do either per the docs, although the advice is to prefer -drain for cross-compatibility.

Comment: Shizam: FWIW, I think you mean to say "instance variable" instead of "class variable". (The latter generally implies a construct that other OOP languages often support but ObjC doesn't.)

Comment: I see, its a variable in the header of the class so I thought its called a 'class variable'.

Comment: Shizam, you are correct. File-static variables are the Objective-C equivalent of class variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is extremely unusual to store a view in a class variable. Why are you doing this?

It is, in general, illegal to access `UIView` on background threads. The docs are a little dodgy on whether construction of a `UIView` is legal on a background thread, but once you dive into `initWithImage:`, it definitely is not explicitly supported and is probably not allowed.

If there is some reason you're creating the `UIImage` on a background thread, that's fine, but then just pass the `UIImage` itself to the main thread and create the view there. You don't need a class variable to pass it between the threads. Just pass it as the object to `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject`.

Comment: Yeah, my suspicion would be that you're seeing some side-effect of creating the view in a background thread.

Comment: I see, thanks, I'll stop creating views in background threads.  The reason I'm doing this is so viewcontrollers that don't need to be displayed immediately can be created in the background and shown once they're done being created.

Comment: There is one thing I still don't understand.  It makes sense to me that I shouldn't manipulate the currently visible view/GUI in a thread but why can't I create views on a thread that aren't tied to what is currently visible.  Why does that cause problems?

Comment: Because the underlying UIKit objects are not thread-safe. It doesn't matter if the view is visible or not. Most UIKit classes assume and rely on the fact that they are accessed exclusively on the main thread. This simplifies UIKit code and improves performance in the common case.